# How to add a PdfPTable to the HTML string in a document at (x,y) location using iText?

Tags: java, android, html, itext

I am doing `html to pdf conversion` using **iText**.

I am already using **HTMLWorker class** (deprecated) having the following content code:

```
    String htmlString = "<html><body> This is my Project <table width= '50%' border='0' align='left' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'><tr><td>{VERTICALTEXT}</td></tr></table></body></html>";

    OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Test.pdf"));
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
    document.open();
    HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
    htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(htmlString ));
    document.close();
    file.close();
}
```

Now I want to replace `{VERTICALTEXT}` dynamically with some string.

**So I further added the code below:**

```
PdfPTable table = null;
PdfPCell cell;
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("My Vertical Text"));
cell.setRotation(90);
cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
table.addCell(cell);
String verticalLoc  = table.toString(); //this variable should hold the text "My Vertical Text" in 90 degree rotated form.

HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("VERTICALTEXT", verticalLoc);

html = new String(buffer);

for (HashMap.Entry<String, String> e : map.entrySet())
{
    String value = e.getValue() != null ? e.getValue():"";
        html = html.replace("{" + e.getKey() + "}", value);
}

htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(htmlStr));
```

**In the Output:**

`{VERTICALTEXT}` is replaced with `com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable@41d62bcO`

**Desired Output:**

`{VERTICALTEXT}` should be replaced with `My Vertical Text` in a 90 degree rotated form.

Comment: Can we set the coordinates of the table (x, y) in the html document ? I added `table.writeSelectedRows(40, 60, 50, 80, writer.getDirectContent()); document.add(table);` but this adds the table at the end of document rather than at exact position where `{VERTICALTEXT}` is in html string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is the solution figured out and tested** -

**Java file relevant code:**

```
static PdfWriter writer;
writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILE));
document.open();
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
PdfPCell cell;
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("My Vertical Text"));
cell.setRotation(90);
cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
table.addCell(cell);
htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(htmlStr));
table.setTotalWidth(400f);
table.writeSelectedRows( 0, -1, 80, 330, writer.getDirectContent());
```

So the magic of method `writeSelectedRows` worked in placing the table to the **(x, y)** location.

Where,

```
x = 80
y = 330
```

Complete details about [writeSelectedRows](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPTable.html#writeSelectedRows%28int,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte%29).

This will help somebody facing the same problems with `itext` positioning.